# Almost 2 month Thawed turkey in refrigerator

Tags: turkey

I was admitted in hospital right before Christmas.Just got back home mid february. Had a whole turkey thawing in fridge, still packaged, no leakage. Is this still any good to cook and eat or definitely toss out? Thank you!

Comment: See [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer) - 2 months is way too long. While it’s thawing it’s still safe, but once it reaches fridge temp (within about a week or so, depending on size of the turkey and fridge/freezer temps) the timelines in the linked question should apply.

Comment: If you unwrap that thing you will truly regret it. Discard unopened.